# Reading objects into an array from a text file with space delimiter

Tags: c++, oop, filestream, ifstream

Good day,

I am trying to read data from a file into an array of objects. I can't seem to find how to tackle the space delimiter. Kindly help me.

The class is called *Rational* and it has two properties: *num* and *denom*.

File data: **1/2  -1/3  3/10  4/5 6/18**

So far I have done this:

```
int operator>>(ifstream& fin, rational r[]) {

    fin.open("filedata.txt", ios::in);
    if (fin)
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            fin >> r[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nData file cannot be found!" << endl;
    }
}

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& in, rational& r)
{
    int num, denom;
    char slash;
    in >> num >> slash >> denom;
    r.set(num,denom);
    return in;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `operator>>(ifstream& in, rational& r)` should work as posted although I would change it to

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, rational& r) { ... }
```

However, the first function is not right. You are not returning anything from the function even though its return type is `int`. You can change it to:

```
int operator>>(ifstream& fin, rational r[])
{
    int count = 0;
    fin.open("filedata.txt", ios::in);
    if (fin)
    {    
        for ( ; count < 5; ++count)
        {
            // If unable to read, break out of the loop.
            if ( !(fin >> r[count] )
            {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nData file cannot be found!" << endl;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Having said that, I think you can improve that function a bit.

1. Open the file in the calling function, `main` maybe, and pass the `std::ifstream` object to it.
2. Instead of passing it an array, pass it a `std::vector`. Then, you don't have worry about the number of entries in the file. You read whatever you can find in the file.
3. Change the return type to be `std::istream&` so you can chain the calls if necessary.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::vector<rational>& v)
{
   rational r;
   while ( in >> r )
   {
      v.push_back(r);
   }
   return in;
}
```

In `main` (or whichever is the higher level function), use:

```
std::vector<rational> v;
std::ifstream fin("filedata.txt);
if ( !fin )
{
   // Deal with error.
}
else
{
   fin >> v;
}

// Use v as you see fit.
```